# Error de iniciar sesión en Firebase usando Facebook en Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, facebook

estoy desarrollando una app en android studio donde uso el inicio de sesión con Facebook, pero al hacer la autenticación con Firebase falla.
Antes funcionaba pero incluí nuevamente la app en otro proyecto en Firebase, ademas copie el archivo google-services.json y se me sigue presentando el problema.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.cancel_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                goMainScreen();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.firebase_error_login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

private void goMainScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoticiasActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
}
}
```

Comment: Buen Día. Andres,Cuál sería el error que se genera al intentar iniciar sesión? Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: Andres es importante revisar el LogCat si deseas desarrollar en Android, agrega el mensaje como comenta Emilio, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: revise el LogCat como me comentan y este es el resultado. 09-13 22:54:05.759 16534-16534/? E/Zygote: v2
09-13 22:54:05.762 16534-16534/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
09-13 22:54:24.867 16534-16534/com.afza.confidencialarauca E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]

Comment: A que te referis con que incluiste nuevamente la app a otro proyecto firebase? tene en cuenta que el google-services.json corresponde a un proyecto y una app en particular.

Comment: Yo tenia un proyecto para ios y uno para android en firebase, luego pase la app de android al mismo proyecto donde esta la de ios, y genere el google-services.json y lo reemplace en mi android studio.